# Upgrading from texlive 2014 to 2016

Tags: texlive, tlmgr

This may be a trivial question. I am looking for an easy approach to upgrade my texlive distribution withouth performing a plain new installation (i.e. removing texlive 2014, dowwnloading and installing texlive 2016).
I am running Ubuntu and have TL installed individually; not from the ubuntu repositories.

In a terminal I can only update packages in the repositories of the specific TL version. For newer updates with `tlmgr` I have to istall a new version of TL.

My question: (How) can I use `tlmgr` to upgrade my TL distribution? I am wondering if my understanding of TL versioning and repositories is correct and this is/is not possible?

Comment: Whilst the manager may be able to update between versions, it's not the recommended approach: you are best to simply install TL'16.

Comment: *"Due to changes in the infrastructure, it is not feasible to upgrade from the TL'15 release to TL'16. (Ditto MacTeX.) Please just do a new installation. "* [https://www.tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html ]

Comment: You need not remove your 2014 installation unless you lack space. This means you can keep your current installation as a fall-back in case something breaks your current documents.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your remarks on the issue. I hoped for easier package management i.e. a more 'linuxish' behaviour.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is solved by comments